# AWS: deploy externally callable docker image via HTTP Rest call

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, rest, amazon-ecs

I'm new to AWS. I have the following problem which I can't solve.
I have a Docker image that contains an executable (Spring Boot) that can run on a machine.
I would like to deploy the image on AWS and make it run in such a way as to make REST calls from my local pc (and subsequently extend it, by calling multiple deployed docker images among themselves).

For now I do this:

1. Upload the image to **AWS ECR** (Elastic Container Registry)
   [image]
2. I create a **task** using **AWS ECS**, to which I allocate a certain amount of memory and link the image using "Container definition":
   [image]
3. I create a **service** (which lives inside a **cluster**) connected to this task always using **AWS ECS**:
   [image]
4. Through the use of **CloudWatch** I am able to see the logs of the running application:
   [image]

What I don't understand is, **how do I get an IP address to which I can (via Postman) make HTTP Rest calls to call my application**?
I would like to try making calls locally, and then deploy other applications on AWS so that they talk to each other using their IP addresses.
Is there anything else I need to do? My steps represent the right way to run a deployed docker image (I don't have the source code)?

Answer (score 0):

You can either set up your cluster to run on EC2 and deploy it in a public subnet.

Or if it is in a private subnet or is fargate hosted you need to set up a load balancer to distribute traffic to your cluster.

https://aws.amazon.com/fr/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-fargate-static-elastic-ip-address/